# D3 XHR, update chart

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I load JSON data from a perl script with D3 XHR and draw a `NVD3 lineWithFocusChart` with that data. The calling of the script and the drawing of the chart is done with the code posted below:

```
$(function() { 
$('#dataForm').on('submit', function(e) { //use on if jQuery 1.7+
    e.preventDefault();  //prevent form from submitting
    console.log("submitted form"); //use the console for debugging

    var runFromDate = document.getElementById("runDateSelectBox1").value;
    var runToDate = document.getElementById("runDateSelectBox2").value;
    var barcode = document.getElementById("barcodesSelectBox").value;

    // console.log(runFromDate);
    // console.log(runToDate);
    // console.log(barcode);


    var dataString = 'runFromDate='+ runFromDate + '&runToDate=' + runToDate + '&barcode=' + barcode;
    //var dataString2 = 'runFromDate'+runFromDate&'runToDate'+runToDate&'barcode'+barcode;
      console.log(dataString);


    // Asynchrounsly request JSON from the perl script.
    // And plot this in the graph
    d3.json("./cgi-bin/parseDatabaseData_v2.pl")
       .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
       .post(dataString,function(error, json){
           console.log("succesfully called script");

            var testdata = json;
            var chart;


            console.log(json);
            nv.addGraph(function() {
              chart = nv.models.lineWithFocusChart()
              .margin({top: 50, right: 60, bottom: 50, left: 80})
              .color(d3.scale.category10().range());


              // Format the 2 x-axes
              chart.xAxis
              .axisLabel('Date')
              .tickFormat(function(d) {
                //var dx = csvData[0].values[d] && csvData[0].values[d].date || 0;
                return d3.time.format('%d-%b-%Y')(new Date(d));
              })
              .showMaxMin(true);

              chart.x2Axis
              .axisLabel('Date')
              .tickFormat(function(d) {
                //var dx = csvData[0].values[d] && csvData[0].values[d].date || 0;
                return d3.time.format('%d-%b-%Y')(new Date(d));
                })
              .showMaxMin(true);

              chart.yAxis
              .axisLabel('Count')
              .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));
              chart.y2Axis
              .axisLabel('Count')
              .tickFormat(d3.format(',f'));

              var chartSVG = d3.select('#chart1 svg')
                .datum(testdata)
                .transition().duration(500).call(chart);

              //console.log(chartSVG);

              nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

              chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });

              return chart;

            }); // End of nv.addgraph


                });
            });
           }); // End of jquery function
```

However when I press the submit button, the script get's called again, but the chart doesn't get updated, as I'd expect.

Can someone clarify what I'd have to change to make the chart update when the submit button is clicked?

Comment: Instead of adding a new graph, update the existing one.

Comment: Hi Lars, thanks for the suggestion, I already figured that the code I've posted above indeed is kind of inefficient. The only question I have now is how I would do this? Because the first time the graph get's drawn when I press the submit button.

Comment: Instead of doing `nv.addGraph`, modify the existing `chart` appropriately and then do `chartSVG.call(chart)`.

Comment: Could you give an example? When I remove the d3 chart code from the ajax call, put it outside and replace it with this: `var chartSVG = d3.select('#chart1 svg').datum(json).transition().duration(500).call(chart);` I get the error: `ReferenceError: chart not defined` which would suggest that I do have to create my chart in the ajax call.